# some characters are saving into text file instead of generated random number

Tags: java, android, file, random

I am building a mobile application where i have to save generated random number into a .txt file. Below you could see my code. When i execute it , .txt file stores some characters instead of numbers. I am new to this file concepts. Please help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int[] arr = new int[100];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        try {
            File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File directory = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyDirectory");
            directory.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(directory, "textfile.txt");
            FileOutputStream fou = new FileOutputStream(file);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fou);
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    Random r = new Random();
                    int c = r.nextInt(100);
                    arr[i] = c;
                    osw.write(c);
                }
                osw.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

// arr[i] is used for later part of my project.

I would be glade if someone help me and help me to rectify my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Writers` use `write(int c)` to write character from Unicode table indexed as `c`.

What you are interested in is writing String which represents your number like `"123"` so first convert it to string and then use `write(String s)` method.

So instead of

```
osw.write(c);
```

use

```
osw.write(String.valueOf(c));
```

Or you can even wrap your writer with `PrintWriter` which has methods like `print`, `println` (similar to `System.out.println`) so you could just use

```
yourPrintWriter.print(c);
```

EDIT:

If you need to print each number in new line then you need to print after it line separator. Try adding

```
osw.write(System.lineSeparator());
```

after printing each number, or use `println` method from `PrintWriter`.

Comment: I need to get numbers 1 by 1. I mean adding a new line. For example if number s generated 123 , I need to save 1 next line 2 and 3rd line 3.How to add new line?

Comment: @user3335796 In that case, use `println` instead of `print`.

Comment: @user3335796 Sorry for late response. Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you foe your help and also for giving information about "ow to accept answer". Its very informative. :-)